# Access 2007, VBA: Checking for duplicates, have null field

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I want to check if a field has duplicates from my **EMP** table. Everything works except I need to create an exception when there's **nothing in the field** aka **null** exception.

```
Private Sub cmdDuplicates2_Click() 
Dim Name As String
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("EMP", dbOpenDynaset)
Name = Me.Personnel
rst.FindFirst "[Personnel] = '" & Name & "'"
If rst.NoMatch Then
        MsgBox "No duplicates found"
  Else
        MsgBox "Name is already in Database"
End If

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** Doing this now. If it's null then it says "Please enter a name." But it also says "No duplicates found." I want it to just say "Please enter a name." *if the field is blank*.

```
Private Sub cmdDuplicates2_Click()
Dim Name As String
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("EMP", dbOpenDynaset)

If IsNull(Me.Personnel) Then MsgBox "Please enter a name." Else: Name = Me.Personnel

rst.FindFirst "[Personnel] = '" & Name & "'"
If rst.NoMatch Then
        MsgBox "No duplicates found"
  Else
        MsgBox "Name is already in Database"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
If IsNull(Me.Personnel) Then Name = "Empty" Else Name = Me.Personnel
```

Comment: I'm trying: **If IsNull(Me.Personnel) Then MsgBox "Please enter a name." Else: Name = Me.Personnel** and it gives me the first msg box but also the second. I don't want the second one ("No dupe found")

Comment: Using MsgBox to prompt for a Name does not result in it being automatically added to your table/database. You'll need to write more code to do that. That's why the "No duplicates found" message.

Comment: Also, your code as written is only looking at the first record returned by the dataset. To find duplicates, assuming that's your intent, you'll need to iterate through all the records one at a time. Or use a [Find Duplicates](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-Duplicates-Easily-in-Microsoft-Access) query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  In this version, I'm actually counting the number of records for each Personnel value:

```
Private Sub cmdDuplicates2_Click() 
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim Qry as string
Qry="Select count(*) from EMP where [Personnel]='" & Me.Personnel & "'"

Set rst = Currentdb.OpenRecordset(Qry, dbOpenDynaset)

If rst.fields(0)>1 then
        MsgBox "Name is already in Database"
  Else
        MsgBox "No duplicates found"
End If

End Sub
```

#### Edit

Sorry, my first instinct was to just refactor your code the way I would do it.  Try adding this to the beginning of your procedure:

```
If Me.Personnel="" then 
    msgbox "Please enter a name."
    exit sub
end if
```

Comment: I want it to do: If null, MsgBox "Please enter a name."

Comment: Sorry about that. Please see above.

Comment: Tried it, the code doesn't seem to run. It skips to the next part.

Comment: It says: Run Time Error "94": Invalid use of null. The highlighted line is the _Name = Me.Personnel_.